Neither Custom Nor Default Sound Coming For iOS FCM Push Notifications
I have been trying to get a custom sound for iOS notification.  I have sound files in caf formats in my main app bundle and they are showing in "Copy bundle resources" in xcode.  when I send notification through firebase console, sound coming. but not getting sound through iOS App.
Payload:
     // General notification data
     notification = new
     {
         title = subject,
         body = "Tina Duo Authentication"
         //,sound = "default" // Using "default" to avoid sound-related errors; update based on the sound file available in your app bundle
     },

     // iOS-specific settings for APNs
     apns = new
     {
         payload = new
         {
             aps = new
             {
                 alert = new
                 {
                     title = subject,
                     body = "Tina Duo Authentication"
                 },
                 sound = "default", // Use "default" or match the actual sound file name without extension
                 badge = 1,
                 mutable_content = "1"
             }
         },
         headers = new
         {
             apns_priority = "10", // Prioritize delivery; valid values are 5 (background) and 10 (alert)
             apns_push_type = "alert" // Must be set correctly for alert type notifications
         }
     },

 

     // Custom data relevant to your application
     data = new
     {
         category = "MyApprove",
         userId = mobileUser.UserName,
         CustomerName = mobileUser.CustomerName,
         is_Tina5s = is_Tina5s.ToString().ToLower(),
         CustomMessage = message,
         badgeCounts = dbCount.ToString(),
         DeviceFingerPrint = mobileUser.FingerPrint
     }
 


What about the iOS part? Does the app ask permission to play sounds on user notifications?
